# AJAX in JS is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i am trying to use ajax in one of JavaScripts to send an email form WebSite.
But it is not working.
I simplified ajax code as much as i can but still it is not working it is like web is totally ignoring this ajax script.

JS/JQuery code

```
    <script>
        function sendMail() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        };
   </script>
```

and Html code is classic button:

```
 <button type="submit" onclick="sendMail()">Use AJAX</button>
```

Is there something wrong?

**EDIT**
I tried both ways as u said (change type to button and also with prevent to submit) but still same problem now code looks like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="sendMail()">Use AJAX</button>


<script>

    function sendMail() {
        alert("test");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

alert("test") is executed properly but ajax is still ignored

Comment: any errors in your console ? CORS maybe ?

Comment: Hard to say with such little code and no clear problem description, but it looks like you don't prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: So just by making a simple request to `http://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/` your expecting to send an email?

Comment: You need an API key to consult the data on this page.

Comment: I am not expecting sending email. I will extend it when this simple code will works I dont have any error. code is simply ignored.
edit: I know i need Api key. But this at least should respond something like"API key is missing"

Comment: try `$('button[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); <put here only the ajax code> });`

Comment: Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` so the button doesn't submit the form.

Comment: @MartinTomko Have you included the `jQuery.js` library in your html?

Comment: @ Alon Eitan Yes in head i have 
 `<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`
  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @MartinTomko The problem is that you're expecting that the ajax will work. It doesn't (or the browser deu to CORS restrictions) - The server reject it (https://jsfiddle.net/dov1yvv5/)

Comment: @ Alon Eitan Thank you, I tried another JSON website and it is responding properly. So problem is that server is rejecting me. Thank you